# Migraciones NameSpace en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2

Estimados tengo este error al ejecutar migrate:

```
WARNING! You have 18 previously executed migrations in the database that are not registered migrations.
>> 2017-08-25 12:57:17 (20170825125717)
>> 2017-08-25 12:59:14 (20170825125914)
>> 2017-09-19 21:06:02 (20170919210602)
>> 2017-09-22 18:30:57 (20170922183057)
>> 2017-09-25 19:00:31 (20170925190031)
>> 2017-09-25 19:49:05 (20170925194905)
>> 2017-09-28 14:59:52 (20170928145952)
>> 2017-09-28 15:47:43 (20170928154743)
>> 2017-09-28 20:48:35 (20170928204835)
>> 2017-11-07 19:05:20 (20171107190520)
>> 2017-11-10 13:26:05 (20171110132605)
>> 2018-01-02 13:47:30 (20180102134730)
>> 2018-01-02 14:40:14 (20180102144014)
>> 2018-01-02 18:29:09 (20180102182909)
>> 2018-01-02 18:29:46 (20180102182946)
>> 2018-02-06 19:07:24 (20180206190724)
>> 2019-05-15 13:10:11 (20190515131011)
>> 2019-05-17 15:13:34 (20190517151334)
Migrating up to 20190612131013 from 20190612131013

++ migrating 20161212180650
```

Se que debo cambiar los namespace pero soy nuevo en symfony, donde debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

No soy ningún exporto en Symfony, pero lo que dice el *warning* es que hay 18 migraciones que no estaban previamente registradas. Nada más. **NO** hay ningún problema con los `namespace`.

Prueba a forzar la migración, o, hacer una migración completa.

Comment: Si, ya realice la migracion completa, tambien hice la comparacion con diff pero sigue el problema. Estimo que hay un problema de incosistencias con la base de datos por eso decia que renombrar los `namespace`.. sabes donde puedo econtrarlos? en Migrations?